# Why I get this skipping when I work with record 'struct' in pascal?

Tags: struct, record, pascal

[image: when i give him the number of item he skip the input of reference and designation and go directly to input of price as shown in the picture]

**when I give him the number of item he skip the input of reference and designation and go directly to input of price as shown in the picture**

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem? Entering the number one, would never escape the repeat..untill loop. And it seems as your problem appears after that loop. A `ReadLn()` would be more UI friendly. And please, do not post code or console output as pictures. Post verbatim!

Comment: Please, never post code as an image, always post code as text (and format it as code in the editor, by selecting it and hitting the `{}` button in the post editor).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your image of the ouput doesn't comply with your code. The code `until ((n>=3)...` doesn't accept a "1" for entry, as your image suggests. Maybe you have changed the code after you made the image.

Secondly, the reason for the program to run through all requests for user input is due to your usage of `read()` instead of `readln()`.

`Read()` reads all characters from the input buffer **up to, but not including the `CRLF`** produced by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. `Read()` leaves the `CRLF` characters in the buffer.

`ReadLn()` reads all characters from the buffer, **including the `CRLF` characters**.

When you call `Read()` after a previous call to `Read()`, the buffer still has the `CRLF` characters from the previous data entry, and there is no reason for the code to wait for those characters, so it just rumbles on with next line(s).

Therefore, use `ReadLn()` instead of `Read()` when you read user entries.